# How to make a csv row for each 2 lines in a txt file

Tags: python, r, bash, awk, sed

I have a text file like this:

```
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz
Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz
Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz
Tomato mottle virus
```

And I need to get a `csv` file like this:

```
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus
```

Because later I want to use this like a tuple to find the compressed file, read it and get a final file with names like:

```
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1/Tomato mottle virus.fna
```

I just need to learn how to do the first part of the problem. It could by with:

- sed
- awk
- R
- Python

Any help would be very appreciated. This is hard for me to accomplish because the original filenames are very messed up.

I have tried this:

```
sed -z 's/\n/,/g;s/,$/\n/' multi_headers
```

However it put comma in all `\n`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box and only storing 1 line at a time in memory so it'll work no matter how large your input file is:

```
$ awk '{ORS=(NR%2 ? "," : RS)} 1' file
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus
```

There's a lot happening in a small amount of code above so here's an explanation:

- `ORS` is the builtin variable containing the string to be printed at the end of each output record (record = line in this case), a newline by default.
- `RS` is the builtin variable containing the string (or regexp) that separates each input record, a newline by default.
- `NR` is the builtin variable containing the current record/line number so `NR%2` is `1` for odd numbered records and 0 for even numbered.
- `NR%2 ? "," : RS` is a [ternary expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) resulting in `,` for odd numbered lines, `\n` (or whatever else you have set `RS` to, e.g. `\r\n`) for even numbered.
- `1` is a true condition which causes the default action of printing the current record to be executed.

So the above script says "if the current line number is odd print it with a `,` at the end, otherwise print it with a newline at the end", hence it's joining every pair of lines with a `,` between.

Answer (score 4):

#### Bash

You can do a `paste` (thanks @glenn jackman for pointing out my previous useless use of `cat`).

```sh
# or cat mytext.txt | paste -d "," - -
paste -d "," - - < mytext.txt 

Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus
```

#### R

The R function is also `paste`, together with `sapply`:

```
mytext <- scan("mytext.txt", character(), sep = "\n")

sapply(seq(1, length(mytext), 2), function(x) paste(mytext[x], mytext[x + 1], sep = ","))
[1] "Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A"
[2] "Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA"           
[3] "Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus"
```

Comment: `^1` for `paste`. I always forget about that...

Comment: UUOC though: `paste -d "," - - < mytext.txt`

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed '/^Viruses/{N;s/\n\(.*\)/,\1/}' multi_headers
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus
```

- `/^Viruses/` - Match lines starting with the string `Viruses`
- `{N;` - Read/append the next line of input into the pattern space.
- `s/\n\(.*\)/,\1/` - Remove the \n from the pattern space and replace it with a comma `,`

Comment: Can you explain this part of the sed command:{N; means? Thank you.

Comment: @PauloSergioSchlogl Please check edit

Comment: beautiful. Thank you very much. I love the power of command line. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

A simple `writerows()`:

```
import csv

with open("text.txt", "r") as f:
    with open("data.csv", "w", newline="") as w:
        writer = csv.writer(w)
        # May want to add headers
        writer.writerow(["Heading1", "Heading2"])
        x = f.readlines()
        writer.writerows([x[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(x), 2)])
```

Which yields:

```
Heading1,Heading2
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus
```

Comment: I am a dumb, I really not used to all the capabilities of the csv module 8(. Thanks man

Comment: That's all good man @PauloSergioSchlogl . There's a lot of ways to solve your problem, this is only one of them.

Comment: This is the best answer, because it relies on `csv` module to make sure resulting CSV is valid, quoting/escaping and all.

Comment: You can use `f.readlines()` instead of `f.read().split("\n")`.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed and paste):

```
sed 'N;s/\n/,/' file
```

Append the next line to the current line and replace the newline between then with a comma.

or:

```
paste -sd',\n' file
```

Paste the file as one long string, replacing every other newline with a comma.

Answer (score 1):

What about this.

```py
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().split('\n')
new_data = []

for a in range(0,len(data),2):
    new_data.append(data[a]+','+data[a+1]+'\n')
    
with open('result.txt','w') as f:
    f.writelines(new_data)
```

## or

```py
with open('test.txt') as f_read, open('result.txt','w') as f_write:
    data = f_read.read().split('\n')
    new_data = []

    for a in range(0,len(data),2):
        new_data.append(data[a]+','+data[a+1]+'\n')

    f_write.writelines(new_data)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another R approach, relying on vector recycling.

```
t = readLines("txt.txt")
paste0(t[c(T, F)], ",", t[c(F, T)]) |> writeLines("txt.csv")
```

or for final file names

```
t = readLines("R/txt.txt")
sub("(?<=\\.\\d).*", "", t, perl = T) |>
  (\(.) paste0(.[c(T, F)], "/", .[c(F, T)], ".fna"))()

#> [1] "Viruses/GCF_000820355.1/Sclerophthora macrospora virus A.fna"
#> [2] "Viruses/GCF_000820495.2/Influenza B virus RNA.fna"           
#> [3] "Viruses/GCF_000837105.1/Tomato mottle virus.fna"
```

Answer (score 1):

Simple `python3` solution, let `file.txt` content be

```
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz
Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz
Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz
Tomato mottle virus
```

and `script.py`

```
with open("file.txt","r") as f:
    for inx, line in enumerate(f):
        print(line.rstrip(), end='\n' if inx%2 else ',')
```

then

```
python script.py
```

output

```
Viruses/GCF_000820355.1_ViralMultiSegProj14361_genomic.fna.gz,Sclerophthora macrospora virus A
Viruses/GCF_000820495.2_ViralMultiSegProj14656_genomic.fna.gz,Influenza B virus RNA
Viruses/GCF_000837105.1_ViralMultiSegProj14079_genomic.fna.gz,Tomato mottle virus
```

Explanation: I use `.rstrip` to jettison trailing newline, then depending on whatever line is odd or even I apply `\n` or `,` respectively as line end. Note that [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) default is starting at 0 as opposed to GNU `AWK` starting at 1. Note that using for ... in filehandle does prevent loading whole file as once, so this solution could be used also for files bigger than available RAM space.

Comment: thats very cool and clever. Thank you very much. I am not a very clever guy 8)

Answer (score 1):

To add yet another solution into the mix, you can also use `xargs` and group input lines by 2, then replace first space with ',' in each output line.

```sh
xargs -n2 -d'\n' -a input.txt | sed 's/ /,/'
```